# Getting the value from a column during a trigger

Tags: sql-server, trigger

After a test completes (on a SQL 2008R2 system), the system updates a row in the TestRun table to include an end time. I am creating a trigger that will take action after that update, and do some post-test analysis for me.

Right now it's very simple.

```
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @errCount Int
    @errCount = exec USF_NumofErrors @RunID = '124'

END
GO
```

However I would like to have that integer replaced with a variable that is the RunID of the row updated (which is causing the trigger to fire).

How can I do that?

Comment: How confident are you that every single update to this table will only affect a single row? This is a common assumption that is almost always wrong, is not always discovered right away, but inevitably leads to the trigger to be re-written without this assumption. Hint: take the logic out of the procedure and perform whatever you're doing in a set-based manner based on the row(s) found in the `inserted` pseudo-table.

Comment: Extremely confident because it's a very closed system, but that's a good thought. I'll read up on the Inserted table.

Comment: What are you then doing with `@errCount`?

Comment: Either way I can confirm that by running a trace on this DB filtered to this table during the next test run to make sure.

Comment: Does your test run encompass every single statement any user will ever issue against this table? Why not make it safe from a multi-row update in any case? Keeping it this way is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: The test run is the only process that touches this table, it's not a database other people have access to or even pull data from. Especially update access. Plus this trigger isn't a long term solution to the problem, it's a short term hack that I'm pulling together to meet the need while we develop a longer term answer, which will probably be outside of SQL anyway and more on the test system side.

@errCount is just a placeholder for now. I'm going to use the count of errors in the run in an insert into a different table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers in SQL Server are fired once per *set*, not per *row* (like Oracle), so you need to build triggers that handle this.

In all triggers, you have two special tables called `inserted` and `deleted`, that contain  a virtual "mirror" of the entire table row(s) after and before the action that triggered it, respectively.

A word of warning: triggers should be small and very light-weight. In your case, running a cursor over your log rows and executing a stored procedure for each row can cause you locking mayhem and slow performance. (Triggers run synchronously, in the same transaction as the original DML statement.)

I would write your solution not in a trigger, but as a separate stored procedure and run it on-demand.

Comment: Ah, I see your point. Update triggers are once per update statement. I'll confirm my assumption before going any further down this path. I'll probably have to figure out a different way to do this.

Comment: Ultimately the only thing I was going to have this trigger do was get a count of the number of errors for the test run that just completed, and insert it (and the runID) onto a different table. But it should be easy to move that logic out somewhere else, I'll just have to create an event in my test code to mark the end of the run.

Comment: INSERT INTO otherTable SELECT runID, COUNT(*) FROM inserted WHERE runFailed=1 GROUP BY runID

Comment: That would work except there is no runFailed column. That's what I'm trying to create, based off of a count of errors (and other things we're defining). No worries though, I'll figure it out.